# Reverse Engineering - EA (Enterprise Architect tool )

Tags: reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

We are trying to generate design document for our source code using EA (Enterprise Architect tool ) 
using code engineering -> Import Source Directory option using Synchronize existing classes.

The problem we are facing is duplicate classes are getting generated for the same file when import source directory is done each time. 
We want the existing classes to be updated. Please provide any solution, We might not be doing the right way of import. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled Overwrite Existing Class option under synchronize?
[image]

If the problem still persists report a [bug to Sparx](https://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html)

Comment: Thanks Arshad it helped. I am adding a "Note" and connecting  to the created class. when import source directory is done once again, the connection link between the new "Note " and the created class is Lost.                                                                                      Is there any way to retain this connection link